# How to mix Django, Uploadify, and S3Boto Storage Backend?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, uploadify, boto, filefield

#### Background

I'm doing fairly big file uploads on Django. File size is generally 10MB-100MB.

I'm on Heroku and I've been hitting the request timeout of 30 seconds.

#### The Beginning

In order to get around the limit, Heroku's [recommendation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#direct_upload) is to upload from the browser DIRECTLY to S3.

Amazon documents this by showing you how to [write an **HTML form**](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) to perform the upload.

Since I'm on Django, rather than write the HTML by hand, I'm using [django-uploadify-s3](https://github.com/sbc/django-uploadify-s3) ([example](https://github.com/sbc/django-uploadify-s3-example)). This provides me with an SWF object, wrapped in JS, that performs the actual upload.

This part is working fine! Hooray!

#### The Problem

The *problem* is in tying that data back to my Django model in a sane way. 
Right now the data comes back as a simple URL string, pointing to the file's location.

However, I was previously using [S3 Boto from django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) to manage all of my files as `FileFields`, backed by the delightful `S3BotoStorageFile`.

To reiterate, S3 Boto is working great in isolation, Uploadify is working great in isolation, the problem is in putting the two together.

My understanding is that the only way to populate the `FileField` is by providing both the [**filename** AND the file **content**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FieldFile.save). When you're uploading files from the browser to Django, this is no problem, as Django has the file content in a buffer and can do whatever it likes with it. However, when doing direct-to-S3 uploads like me, Django only receives the file name and URL, not the binary data, so I can't properly populate the `FieldFile`.

#### Cry For Help

Anyone know a graceful way to use S3Boto's FileField in conjunction with direct-to-S3 uploading?

Else, what's the best way to manage an S3 file just based on its URL? Including setting expiration, key id, etc.

Many thanks!

Comment: So change it to a URLField? After all you don't have the file, just a url.

Comment: Good solution, but is there an easy way to build some S3 intelligence (expiration, credentials) into the URLField? Or do I write that logic myself?

Comment: Dig around, perhaps someone has solved this already and put up their solution; but very likely something to do yourself.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I am exactly at the same situation... Did you find a good solution to this problem you could share?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#urlfield).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where i want to store file to s3 either directly using FileField or i have an option for the user to input the url directly. So to circumvent that, i used 2 fields in my model, one for FileField and one for URLField. And in the template i could use 'or' to see which one exists and to use that like {{ instance.filefield or instance.url }}.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but you should be able to use:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
f = default_storage.open('name_you_expect_in_s3', 'r')
#f is an instance of S3BotoStorageFile, and can be assigned to a field
obj, created = YourObject.objects.get_or_create(**stuff_you_know)
obj.s3file_field = f
obj.save()
```

I think this should set up the local pointer to s3 and save it, without over writing the content.

ETA: You should do this only after the upload completes on S3 and you know the key in s3.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [django-filetransfers](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers). Looks like it plays nice with django-storages.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used django, so ymmv  :) but why not just write a single byte to populate the content? That way, you can still use FieldFile.

Comment: Because doing so actually creates a 1-byte file on disk and auto-updates the corresponding URL to point at that 1-byte file. :(

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking that writing actual SQL may be the easiest solution here. Alternatively you could subclass S3BotoStorage, override the _save method and allow for an optional kwarg of filepath which sidesteps all the other saving stuff and just returns the cleaned_name.